# JDBC show records in JLabel when button clicked

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jlabel

```
public class d4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Connection con;
String dbName = "mydb";
String bdUser = "root";
String dbPassword = "2323";
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
JButton showButton;
static JLabel[] lbl;
JPanel panel;

public d4() {

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, bdUser, dbPassword);
        System.out.println("Connected to database successfully!");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to database");
    }

    add(mypanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 500);
    setLocation(300, 30);
    setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel mypanel() {
    panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    showButton = new JButton("Show");
    showButton.addActionListener(this);
//        lbl = recordsLabel();
//        for (JLabel jlabel : lbl) {
//            panel.add(jlabel);               // Make no sense , Why?
//        }
    panel.add(showButton);

    return panel;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new d4();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == showButton) {
//
    }
}
    public JLabel[] recordsLabel() {
    try {
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
        ArrayList<String> lableList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (result1.next()) {
            String resultRow = result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2);
            System.out.println(resultRow);
            lableList.add(resultRow);
        }
        Object[] arrayResultRow = lableList.toArray();

        int rows = result1.last() ? result1.getRow() : 0;
        System.out.println("Number of rows is: " + rows);

        lbl = new JLabel[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            lbl[i] = new JLabel(arrayResultRow[i].toString());
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Can not excute sql statement");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lbl;
}
}
```

Output:

```
Connected to database successfully!
10 sajjad
11 hamed
12 mehdi
13 hasan
555 fcvc
5858 cccc
1200 world
10 sajjad
1200 world
1200 world
1200 world
555 yes
333 ttt
1200 world
Number of rows is: 14
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: -1 a bounty doesn't make much sense as long as you don't state your problem (especially after the edit which fixed some obvious issues)

Comment: @ViktorSeifert i want to see jlabels when click to showbutton, Not when program is run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `return` statement from inside the loop .The loop breaks once it encounters the `return` and gives back the caller of the method only the first record.

```
while (result1.next()) {
        System.out.println(result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2));
// instead of returning from here , you can create labels and set the text
// and return a List of labels.
        return result1.getString(1) + " "+ result1.getString(2); 
}
```

Loop through the `resultset` and populate some Collection and return the Collection at the end of the method once the loop ends. Also create labels , you have created only one label and setting the text of it from the return value of the `showRecords2()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your label inside the loop, instead returning the values, since it breaks the iteration after the first row

```
while (result1.next()) {
        System.out.println(result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2));

        // Create your label here, for the current text
}
```

Comment: `while (result1.next())` will iterate as long as there are results to fetch. There is no way to know hoy many rows are in a ResultSet. Every `System.out...` is a row... If you want to create a label for each row, yo should do that after the `System.out...`

Answer (score 1):

You can't read every ResultSet row more than once.
But you can store result value.

you can try

```
Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
while (result1.next()) {
    String resultRow = result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2);
    System.out.println(resultRow);
    set.add(resultRow);
}
String[] resultRows = (String[])set.toArray();

int rows = result1.last() ? result1.getRow() : 0;
System.out.println("Number of rows is: " + rows);      // print 14 correctly!

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    lbl = new JLabel[rows];
    lbl[i].setText(resultRows[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

toArray method in Set class returns an object array.
you can't cast Object array to String array.

try this code:

```
public JLabel recordsLabel() {
    try {
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        while (result1.next()) {
            String resultRow = result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2);
            System.out.println(resultRow);
            set.add(resultRow);
        }
        Object[] arrayResultRow = set.toArray();

        System.out.println("Number of rows is: " + arrayResultRow.length);

        lbl = new JLabel[arrayResultRow.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayResultRow.length; i++) {
             lbl[i]=new JLabel(arrayResultRow[i].toString());
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Can not excute sql statement");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

you can do it like this to:

```
public JLabel recordsLabel() {
    try {
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
        ArrayList<String> labelsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (result1.next()) {
            String resultRow = result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2);
            System.out.println(resultRow);
            labelsList.add(resultRow);
        }

        System.out.println("Number of rows is: " + labelsList.size());

        lbl = new JLabel[labelsList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < labelsList.size(); i++) {
            lbl[i]=new JLabel(labelsList.get(i));
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Can not excute sql statement");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the new version that works without any exception.

```
class d4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Connection con;
String dbName = "mydb";
String bdUser = "root";
String dbPassword = "2323";
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
JButton showButton;
static JLabel[] lbl;

public d4() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, bdUser,dbPassword);
        System.out.println("Connected to database successfully!");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to database");
    }

    add(mypanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 500);
    setLocation(300, 30);
    setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel mypanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    showButton = new JButton("Show");
    showButton.addActionListener(this);
    lbl = recordsLabel();
    for (JLabel jLabel : lbl) {
        panel.add(jLabel);

    }
    panel.add(showButton);

    return panel;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    new d4();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == showButton) {
        recordsLabel();     
        //     mypanel().add(recordsLabel());       // Error
    }
}

public JLabel[] recordsLabel() {
    try {
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
        ArrayList<String> lableList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (result1.next()) {
            String resultRow = result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2);
            System.out.println(resultRow);
            lableList.add(resultRow);
        }
        Object[] arrayResultRow = lableList.toArray();

        int rows = result1.last() ? result1.getRow() : 0;
        System.out.println("Number of rows is: " + rows);

        lbl = new JLabel[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            lbl[i] = new JLabel(arrayResultRow[i].toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception sqle) {
        System.out.println("Can not excute sql statement");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        lbl=new JLabel[0];
    }
    return lbl;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

this works good:

```
class d4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Connection con;
String dbName = "mydb";
String bdUser = "root";
String dbPassword = "2323";
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/onbook";
JButton showButton;
static JLabel[] lbl;
JPanel myPanel;

public d4() throws ClassNotFoundException {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, bdUser,dbPassword);
        System.out.println("Connected to database successfully!");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to database");
    }


     showButton = new JButton("Show");
    showButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(showButton,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 500);
    setLocation(300, 30);
    setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel mypanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    lbl = recordsLabel();
    for (JLabel jLabel : lbl) {
        panel.add(jLabel);
    }
    return panel;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    new d4();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == showButton) {
        add(mypanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START); 
        setVisible(true);
        //     mypanel().add(recordsLabel());       // Error
    }

}

public JLabel[] recordsLabel() {
    try {
        Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
        ArrayList<String> lableList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (result1.next()) {
            String resultRow = result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2);
            System.out.println(resultRow);
            lableList.add(resultRow);
        }
        Object[] arrayResultRow = lableList.toArray();

        int rows = result1.last() ? result1.getRow() : 0;
        System.out.println("Number of rows is: " + rows);

        lbl = new JLabel[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            lbl[i] = new JLabel(arrayResultRow[i].toString());
        }

    } catch (Exception sqle) {
        System.out.println("Can not excute sql statement");
        sqle.printStackTrace();
        lbl=new JLabel[0];
    }
    return lbl;
}}
```

Comment: i'm sorry. just change this part:
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/onbook"